# Git Bash (mingw64) - make does not do anything

Tags: windows, makefile, git-bash

I am currently working on a workstation on Windows 10 and Git Bash.

Git Bash is the most viable option right now, as this is what our Travis CI uses and the team mostly work on Unix workstations.

I can't seem to be able to build anything with the Git Bash built-in `make`. The invocation does not fail, but just does not do anything (with or without explicit targets, Makefile location...).

Anyone has encountered this before?

Comment: Git Bash does not provide any built-in `make` program.  I don't know what you are running when you type `make`, but it's not a make program that was provided with Git Bash.  Try `type -a make` in Git Bash to see what is being invoked.  If someone else installed a make program you can try running `make --version` or `make -v` etc. to see what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Git Bash is the most viable option right now,

A more viable option, which would allow to install make, and have a greated compatibility, would be [WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).

If you can activate that feature (WSL) on your Windows 10, you will have a true Linux session, compatible with any Unix work.

Comment: let me try that :)